# How hard is it to build an iOS application like this?

Tags: ios, iphone, network-programming

I am a *Web Designer* and I don't know much about programming, well, I know *literally nothing* about iOS programming.

And I need a iOS app that can do these things for me:

1. It will take photos.
2. It will ask for some inputs from photo-taker like Name, E-Mail
   etc.
3. The program will change the name of the taken photo with inputs
   which program took in the first place, like name and e-mail. For
   example, IPhone21313.JPG ---> Leo_Maxim__leomaxim@example.org.JPG
4. Then it will send the photo to a specific folder in a web server
   like a FTP client.

Is it possible?

Even if it is possible, how hard is it to build some sort of a program like this one? Could any average iOS programmer accomplish to build this kinda program?

I know it was a long question, but I need your help, really.

Thank you!

Comment: Not that hard, feature-wise. Reading half of *iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide* should be more than enough to be able to build it (hint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Take a picture:**

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_7_iPhone_Camera_Application

---

**Get input:**

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation--mobile-8388
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate--mobile-10943

---

**Save the image:**

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/save-uiimage-object-as-a-png-or-jpeg-file.html

---

**FTP Example:**

https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager

---

Bottom line, it's extremely easy.